# Use custom html for cluster background instead of image

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to use html elements as background for a cluster instead of images (for example [m1.png](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/images/m1.png)) as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering?hl=en#adding-a-marker-clusterer), with Google Maps JS api and `MarkerClusterer`?